# Apparently I can't retain GameObjects in a Prefab. How do I get around this?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I need my Main Camera to be in the cam variable slot for my Deletion script, in order to delete each prefab as it goes out of view. How do I accomplish this?[image]

Comment: In this case you can just remove the Cam field and access the camera directly in any script by using Camera.main

Comment: Is Camera.main a rigidbody? and if not how do I get its position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good talk about pools here.
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/321762/how-to-assign-variable-to-a-prefabs-child.html
And for objects in the camera here.
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8003/how-can-i-know-if-a-gameobject-is-seen-by-a-partic.html